# Jmeter Performance Plugin

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to install Jmeter Performance plugin , after trying everything for proxy , i am still not able to make it work.
I get error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KLhl.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status 407](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/407) means

> The **HTTP 407 Proxy Authentication Required** client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it **lacks valid authentication credentials for a proxy server** that is between the browser and the server that can access the requested resource.

You need to supply your proxy username and password via [JMeter's command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -u your_proxy_username -a your_proxy_password
```

the proxy parameters like host and port can either be set via command-line options as well:

```
jmeter -H your_proxy_host -P your_proxy_port -u your_proxy_username -a your_proxy_password
```

alternatively proxy host and port can be stored in [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

```
http.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
https.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
http.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
https.proxyPortyour_proxy_port
```

References:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
- [Plugins Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/)

Comment: i have already added these settings in my system.properties file to run a test that can only be accessed behind a proxy. i am not using password there. Still not able to use Plugin manager.(I have never used username and password with proxy). Is there anything else i am doing wrong or need to check.

Comment: If you haven't used your password it might be NTLM proxy authentication (you're automatically being logged in using your domain credentials), it doesn't mean the proxy doesn't require a password, HTTP status 407 means that it actually does require credentials

Comment: we don't use a username and password for proxy , but i am using JMeter in a remote box that needs username and password, do you mean i should use that domain username and password along with the proxy. sorry if that does not make any sense.